# Which embedded processors are the closest to multicore

Tags: c, linux, embedded, x86, embedded-linux

Which embedded processors are the closest to x86 multicore systems, that is, which has shared memory, cache coeherence and memory management etc. I am asking because I want to know how easy it is to port system applications written for x86 to embedded systems. I am especially interested in embedded systems using Linux (Embedded Linux).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MIPS, Arm, Tilera, Cavium , Freescale and IBM (PowerPC) all make processors that fit what you describe.

Comment: @MetallicPriest all of those can deliver devices with MMU. Cache coherence I am not so sure about. At least there are PPC dual cores out there without automatic cache coherence, you may want to keep an eye open for that.

Comment: look at the arm mpcore, it might have what you are looking for as well.

Comment: @MetallicPriest yes, all of these companies sell (also) chips with MMU and hardware cache coherency.

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of embedded multicore x86 platforms in the world, when you get up to the larger end of embedded systems.

Beyond that, the world is full of embedded processors that run Linux in a "normal" way, with cache coherence and MMUs and so forth.  In general, if you have a program that doesn't use any x86-specific assembly or compiler intrinsics and doesn't make inappropriate assumptions about pointer/long/int sizes, you can port it to a wide range of embedded processors with just a simple re-compile.